# script does not switch to another user

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am working on a script that at a certain point needs to switch to the root user (executing "sudo rootsh" is the only accepted way to switch to root on our servers,) after which it will execute a certain command.

I am not sure what I am missing, but the script simply ignores the part when it should switch to root and continues executing the commands with the user that started the script.

If you check the generated `whoami.txt` file, you will notice that the user is not root. Please keep in mind that the user executing the script can switch to root without any issue while executing the sudo rootsh command.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import subprocess
def switch_user():
 commands = '''
 sudo rootsh
 whoami > whoami.txt
 sysctl -a | grep kernel.msgmni'''
 process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 out, err = process.communicate(commands.encode('utf-8'))
switch_user()
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `sudo rootsh` spawns a _new_ shell session with root permissions.  It does not affect the current shell session.

Comment: If you want to affect the current process, you'll have to use something like `os.seteuid()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Popen`ing a subprocess to run `bash`, and from *that* opening a separate privileged shell, `Popen` the command `sudo rootsh` directly.  If that succeeds (requires that the user be permitted to `sudo rootsh` *without providing a password*) then deliver the rest of the commands by communicating with the subprocess.

That would be something along these lines:

```
import subprocess

def switch_user():
    # These shell commands will be used as input to the root shell
    commands = '''whoami > whoami.txt
    sysctl -a | grep kernel.msgmni'''

    # Launch the root shell
    process = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/sudo rootsh',
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Send the shell's input to it and receive back its output
    out, err = process.communicate(commands.encode('utf-8'))

switch_user()
```

You may need to modify that for your purposes.  In particular, if your `sudo` command lives at a different location then you may need to modify the path to it.  And I emphasize again that this approach depends on being able to obtain a root shell without providing a password.  Sudo can be configured that way, but it is not the default.

Comment: This seems to be a great idea, would it be possible for you to give me a code sample? I tried adding the commands into a variable (variable = ["command"] and then calling subprocess.Popen(['sudo rootsh'] + "variable" shell=True stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE but unfortunately, I still get the same result. Thanks!

Comment: @CatalinS., I have added a modified version of your original code that shows the changes I described.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your answer, I just tried your method but after executing the code, I get the following error: File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1238, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to make this work after doing a more thorough investigation with the guys from the OS team. I'll post this, maybe it would be useful for somebody in the future:

```
import os
os.system("sudo rootsh -i -u root 'sysctl -a | grep kernel.msgmni' > parameter_value.txt")
```

The key was to insert the `-i` and `-u` options:

> #### -i [command]
>
> The `-i` (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login
>   shell.
>                    This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell.  If a command is
>   specified, it is
>                    passed to the shell for execution via the shell's `-c` option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.
>   `sudo`
>                    attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell.  The security policy shall initialize the
>   environment to a
>                    minimal set of variables, similar to what is present when a user logs in.  The *Command Environment* section in the
>   `sudoers(5)` manual documents how the `-i` option affects the environment in which a command is run when the `sudoers` policy is in use.

> #### -u user
>
> The `-u` (user) option causes `sudo` to run the specified command as a user other than root.  To specify a uid instead
>   of a user name, `#uid`.
>                    When running commands as a uid, many shells require that the `#` be escaped with a backslash ('`\`').  Security policies may
>   restrict uids
>                    to those listed in the password database.  The `sudoers` policy allows uids that are not in the password database as
>   long as the `targetpw`
>                    option is not set.  Other security policies may not support this.

Thank you all for your answers :)

Comment: `-u root` achieves nothing - the default is to run the command as root.  The real thing you did that helped is to pass the commands to `sudo` to run as argument, rather than as separate commands after `sudo` finishes.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `grep` - just `sysctl kernel.msgmni` should be sufficient, and more robust.